# Changing Keyboard Shortcuts in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I want to change the functionality of some keyboard shortcuts, and add some custom ones, to Terminal in OSX such that:

1. `alt + delete` deletes one word to the left
2. `cmd + i` selects my entire input

I have entered "Terminal" -> "Preferences" -> (selected profile) -> keyboard, and see a table that I can't decipher. I also can't find anything on google that maps the esoteric symbology to "actions" (I assume that `\033[3~` means "delete," for example).

How can I change the shortcuts of terminal to achieve my 2 goals above, or, where can I find a guide to map the symbols displayed in my example above (also see image) to "actions?"

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Preferences]

This question is not related to [adding keyboard shortcuts for OSX terminal or xterm](https://superuser.com/questions/306414/adding-keyboard-shortcuts-for-osx-terminal-or-xterm) because I am not trying to assign a bash function / command to a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I aware of changing default keyboard/mouse behavior is `Karabiner`.

You can do

> > 1. `alt + delete` deletes one word to the left

1. Install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html). It is really handy tool for key mappings.
2. In `Preferences>Complex Modifications` click on `Add Rule`
3. Now click on `Import more rules from the Internet`
4. In the browser window that will open click on `Application Specific`
5. Against `Navigation in Terminal Apps` click on `Import` button
6. You will be asked to open the downloaded file, do it in `Karabiner.app`
7. You will see a list of options. Import them.
8. Now in `Preferences>Complex Modifications` click on `Add Rule`
9. Against ⌥ + ⌫ `Delete one word` click on `Enable`

---

As for

> > 2.`cmd + i` selects my entire input

MacOS Terminal app does not allow to select text without mouse (unless you want to select all text in the current window with ⌘+A). So if you want to select text you need to emulate mouse.

You can add this code to `karabiner.json` to produce triple click.

```
               {
                    "description": "⌥ + i | Select current line",
                    "manipulators": [
                        {
                            "conditions": [
                                {
                                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                                        "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                                        "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                                        "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                                        "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                                }
                            ],
                            "from": {
                                "key_code": "i",
                                "modifiers": {
                                    "mandatory": [
                                        "option"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "to": [
                                {
                                    "pointing_button": "button1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "pointing_button": "button1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "pointing_button": "button1"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "basic"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

---

Those "actions" are terminal [escape sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html). They are really ancient. `\033` is escape character, followed by some other key codes. So basically this are key mappings.

Comment: Wow, you really know your stuff! This obviously fulfill the bounty.